# Setup kubectl with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Does anyone know how to setup kubectl with jenkins?
Jenkins is running on AWS EC2 which can communicate with AWS EKS Cluster.

when i run shell script in jenkins as kubectl version i get :

```
+ kubectl version
```

output :

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10",    GitVersion:"v1.10.3",     GitCommit:"2bba0127d85d5a46ab4b778548be28623b32d0b0",     GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-07-26T20:40:11Z",     GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Error from server (Forbidden): <html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2Fversion'/>    <script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2Fversion');</script></head>    <body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->

</body></html>
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove ~/ from aws eks export commands and then you can easily setup kubectl for aws eks.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to configure it in proper way is to use [Jenkins Kubernetes plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Kubernetes+Plugin): https://illya-chekrygin.com/2017/08/26/configuring-certificates-for-jenkins-kubernetes-plugin-0-12/

Another one is to pass cluster kubeconfig file to kubectl.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that. Check the link below posted by **AWS**. According to the link. When it comes to EKS you can use  **Jenkins X**. It's designed for K8s only.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/continuous-delivery-eks-jenkins-x/